# Java date handling in improper format

Tags: java

Firstly, I'm a C# dev learning Java.  I'm converting a program I wrote in C# as an exercise and am having problems with parsing a date being submitted from an html form.  The form is sent as an email and the java program reads the emails and parses the body.  I have a drop down calendar for my peeps to select a date from but there's always some jerk who has to type it in and mess everything up. Currently I am doing this in my code:

```
public void SetDatePlayed(String datePlayed)
{
    this.datePlayed = LocalDate.parse(datePlayed);
}
```

datePlayed being passed in is a string usually formatted as yyyy-MM-dd but of course someone typed in 3/7 instead of using the calendar drop down on the form.  this.datePlayed is a LocalDate.  In C# I would just end up with a date that assumed 2020 for the year - no problem.  LocalDate really wants it in the yyyy-MM-dd format and I don't know what the best practice here is with Java.  I've been googling it all morning and haven't come across this as being an issue for anyone else.  I don't care if I'm using LocalDate but I do need it to be a date datatype so I can do date checks, sorts, searches, etc later on.

Comment: "In C# I would just end up with a date that assumed 2020 for the year" What C# API handles both `yyyy-MM-dd` and `3/7` formats? I don't recall such a thing...

Comment: I'd look inside `DateTimeFormatter` and see how it does the parsing. Especially bits that use `java.time.format.ResolverStyle#SMART`

Comment: @Sweeper sure try DateTime.Parse("3/7") and you'll see you get a value of 3/7/2020 12:00:00AM.  99% of my input coming through my website uses yyyy-MM-dd so I know it's able to deal with both formats.

Comment: @user1572 Oh, you meant that... I never dared to let it guess the format like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and [`parseDefaulting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) to supply default value for the year.

Building on the [answer by Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156840/5221149), it can be done like this:

```
static LocalDate parseLoosely(String text) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("[uuuu-M-d][M/d/uuuu][M/d]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())
            .toFormatter();
    return LocalDate.parse(text, fmt);
}
```

<sup>*Warning:* Do not cache the formatter in e.g. a `static` field, since it snapshots the year, if the program might be running across New Year's Eve, which a webapp would, unless you add logic to make the cache auto-refresh on year change.</sup>

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parseLoosely("2019-04-07"));
System.out.println(parseLoosely("2019-4-7"));
System.out.println(parseLoosely("4/7/2019"));
System.out.println(parseLoosely("4/7"));
```

*Output*

```
2019-04-07
2019-04-07
2019-04-07
2020-04-07
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible interpretations of your question. I'm not sure which one it is, so I'll answer both.

> How do I parse a date string in a format that has no year, such as `M/d` (`3/7`), to a `LocalDate`?

You don't. A `LocalDate` by definition must have year, month, and day. If you only have a month and a day, that's a `MonthDay`:

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse("3/7", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d"));
```

If you want the current year added to it, you can do it later:

```
LocalDate ld = md.atYear(Year.now(/*optionally insert time zone*/).getValue());
```

> How do I handle both `yyyy-MM-dd` and `M/d` patterns?

Here's one way: create a `DateTimeFormatter` that recognises both patterns, parse the string to a `TemporalAccessor`, check if the `TemporalAccessor` supports the "year" field:

```
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[M/d][yyyy-MM-dd]").parse("3/7");
if (ta.isSupported(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA)) { // yyyy-MM-dd
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from(ta);
} else if (ta.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) { // M/d
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.from(ta);
} else {
    // user has entered an empty string, handle error...
}
```

Comment: You actually *can* parse a date string in a format that has no year. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156962/5221149), which builds on the solution you have at the bottom.

Comment: @Andreas Ahh~ `parseDefaulting`! I knew there has to be a method like this after writing my answer, I was going to add it at the end as an alternative way, but couldn't find what the method was called...